# Removing few characters from a string using wild card

Tags: string, excel, replace, excel-formula, worksheet-function

*emphasized text*

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmzRL.jpg]

I used string function but the result becomes skewed if the number of digits in parentheses varies.

How do I sort this issue?

Comment: =TRIM(LEFT(A1,FIND("(",A1) - 1))

Comment: I never expected to get answer under a minute. You guys are awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find & Select seems quite up to the task:

[image: SO33638050 example]

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(A1,FIND("(",A1) - 1))
```

The idea is first you FIND the "(" character, then you take all characters to the LEFT of the "(" character. Then you TRIM all excess whitespace. This is a bit more dynamic, as there may be more than one 'space'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" (",A1))
```

Comment: Thank you so much this worked fine. I am going to hang around this forum and learn a ton.